# Display incorrect image from api file

Tags: ios, uitableview

I tried to get image from api and display it on UITableView. However, image does not display correctly after the list group by section header. I have no idea how to fix it and display correct image for each row of records.

For my image, will get URL link like http://www.domain_name.com/Images/Merchant/abc.jpg.

Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Friend_ViewController.h"
#import "FriendDetails_ViewController.h"
#import "AFHTTPSessionManager.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"


@interface Friend_ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating>

@end

@implementation Friend_ViewController{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    UITableView *tableView;
    BOOL isFiltered;
    NSMutableArray *stateNamesArray;
    NSMutableArray *stateNamesArrayImage;
    NSMutableArray *searchResult;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = ThemeBlueColor;
    self.tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.rowHeight = 60;

    isFiltered =false;
    self.navigationItem.title=@"Friends";
    UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Add_Friend"];

    CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0,0, image3.size.width -10, image3.size.height);

    UIButton *btn_add_friends = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
    [btn_add_friends setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_add_friends addTarget:self action:@selector(addFriendButtonDidPressed:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btn_add_friends setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];

    UIBarButtonItem *btn_add_friends_item =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn_add_friends];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =btn_add_friends_item;

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    [manager GET:@"http://api.domain_name.com/api/merchant" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

     stateNamesArray=[responseObject valueForKey:@"merchant_name"];
     stateNamesArrayImage=[responseObject valueForKey:@"image"];

     NSInteger indexLabelLettersCount = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles].count;

     NSMutableArray *allSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:indexLabelLettersCount];

     for (int i = 0; i < indexLabelLettersCount; i++) {
     [allSections addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
     }

     for(NSString *theState in stateNamesArray){

     NSInteger sectionNumber = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForObject:theState collationStringSelector:@selector(lowercaseString)];

     [allSections[sectionNumber] addObject:theState];
     }

     NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     self.activeSectionIndices = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
     self.activeSectionTitles = [NSMutableArray array];

     for (int i = 0; i < indexLabelLettersCount; i++) {

     NSArray *statesForSection = allSections[i];

     NSString *indexTitleForSection = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles][i];

     if (statesForSection.count > 0) {

     [self.activeSectionTitles addObject:indexTitleForSection];

     NSArray *tmpSectionStates = allSections[i];

     tmpSectionStates = [tmpSectionStates sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

     [sortedArray addObject:tmpSectionStates];
     }

     NSNumber *index = [NSNumber numberWithInt:MAX(self.activeSectionTitles.count - 1, 0)];

     self.activeSectionIndices[indexTitleForSection] = index;

     }

     tableData = sortedArray;

     self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 25;
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

     tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
     self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

     self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
     self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

     self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

     self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
     self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
     self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
     self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
     self.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = ThemeLightGrayColor;
     self.searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 0;

     self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
     [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];

     [self.view addSubview:self.searchBar];
     searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[stateNamesArray count]];

     [self.tableView reloadData];

     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

     UIAlertController *alertVC = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving Ninjas"
                                                                      message:[error localizedDescription]
                                                               preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];`enter code here`

     UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                                        style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                                      handler:nil];

     [alertVC addAction:okAction];

     [self presentViewController:alertVC animated:YES completion:nil];
     }];

}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(nonnull NSString *)searchText
{
    //[searchText removeAllObjects];
    if(searchText.length == 0)
    {
        isFiltered = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        isFiltered = YES;

        NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                        predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS %@",
                                        searchText];

        searchResult = [stateNamesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *) tableView{
    return isFiltered ? 1 : tableData.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(isFiltered){
        return searchResult.count;
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *arr = tableData[section];
        return arr.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }

    if(isFiltered){
        cell.textLabel.text = [searchResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[stateNamesArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
    else{

        NSArray *arr = tableData[indexPath.section];//get the current section array
        cell.textLabel.text = arr[indexPath.row];//get the row for the current section

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[stateNamesArrayImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    FriendDetails_ViewController *FriendDetails_ViewControl = [[FriendDetails_ViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:FriendDetails_ViewControl animated:YES];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if(isFiltered)
    {
        return nil;
    }
    return self.activeSectionTitles[section];
}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    NSArray *letterIndexLabels = [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles];
    return letterIndexLabels;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return [self.activeSectionIndices[title] integerValue];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why aren't the image URLs in the same data array as the text? Don't have two separate arrays. Just have one. Use a class to represent all of the data for a given row. Then have an array of arrays of that row class. Much, much easier that trying to organize two separate data arrays.

Comment: Hi Rmaddy, Thanks for your prompt reply. I am new in IOS development. Mind to show me more about how to do tat? I have no idea and stuck at here. Thx

Comment: Why don't you try using a library for image loading? Try this one. How to use is there on github - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: @Test87 can you please show details what data comes in [responseObject valueForKey:@"image"];

Comment: i have some time so lets try to solve your error  please come an join this  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162783/display-incorrect-image-from-api-file

Comment: Hi Sumit, i cant join the chat due to my low reputation.  [responseObject valueForKey:@"image"];  will show  http://www.domain_name.com/Images/Merchant/abc.jpg